# Can vim's command-line-window be configured to *not* shift the buffer's contents?

Tags: vim

When vim's command line window is opened (`:help command-line-window`),
it shifts the buffer's contents up by its height.  Is there any way to
tell it to not shift?

Here's an example of what I'm referring to:

[image: recording of vim buffer shifting]

Ideally, the command window would open and simply overlap the bottom few
rows.

My assumption is that the command line window is a true split, and thus
may not be able to "overlap" the other split (the main buffer).  Can't
hurt to ask, though.

Answer (score 3):

You **could** get *somewhere* closer by using

```
:set scrolloff=N
```

In this case, having it at 5 would have approximated the desired effect:

[image]

I know this is cheating a bit (my main window is bigger) and it is fiddly (it uses information from your specific starting view to keep the line shown). However, it's not unthinkable you might script this to 'magically' work when you press <kbd>q:</kbd>.

In a perfect world, I'd use `:mkview!` (or equivalent script commands) with mappings to save and restore window positions. However, the command window is special, and it doesn't allow switching of windows, so I don't think it's possible.

Comment: (Side note, breaking SO rules: what's the keypress display widget you have in the upper right?  Love it)

Comment: Hmm, interesting.  I tried this but it didn't have any effect.  I already have `so=3` in my vimrc.  With a reasonably large window, I don't quite grok how `so` would help unless it could be set to 50%.

Comment: @mwcz I think I mentioned this: "and it is fiddly". And so, my reply is still the same: "it's not unthinkable you might script this" - IOW In the `:set so=<N>` command, `<N>` could be dynamically evaluated depending on the current topmost line... (oh, and just press "Edit" or [view history, view source](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/34b21463-bb7a-4569-90b9-5f36bac274f4/view-source) to peek at my markdown :))